# Tkinter alter child window from parent

Tags: python, tkinter

Trying make two windows. One to display an random image, the other has a button which changes to a new random image. Currently if I put a timer in the Display.update_image() and call it in the `Display.__init__`, I can get it to change picture regularly.

But putting the `update_image()` command in a button on the parent window doesn't work. Is it possible to alter the second window from the first?

```
    import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import random


def top_100():
    """ 
    Returns a list of the top 100 biggest NZ cities. 
    """
    file = open("Top100NZcities.csv")
    cities = file.readlines()
    return [city.strip() for city in cities]


class UserInt():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.root)
        self.app = Display(self.newWindow)

        self.random_100_button = tk.Button(text = 'Random from top 100', 
                                           width = 50, 
                                           command = self.app.update_image())    
        self.random_100_button.pack()
        self.root.mainloop()   


class Display():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.root = master

        #Get the list of cities,.
        self.cities = top_100()

        #Set to fullscreen.
        w, h = self.root.winfo_screenwidth(), self.root.winfo_screenheight()
        self.root.overrideredirect(1)
        self.root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))        

        #Display initial image.
        self.image_init = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("black_background.jpg"))
        self.panel = tk.Label(self.root, image=self.image_init)
        self.display = self.image_init
        self.panel.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.YES)

    def update_image(self):
        """
        Replaces the screen's current image with a new random image.
        """
        self.city = random.choice(self.cities)
        self.image_rand = Image.open("NZ maps/{}_nz.png".format(self.city))

        #Rescale image to fit window.
        w, h = self.root.winfo_screenwidth(), self.root.winfo_screenheight()        
        self.scale_factor = h / self.image_rand.height
        self.scaled_image = self.image_rand.resize(
            (int(self.scale_factor * self.image_rand.width), h), Image.ANTIALIAS
        )
        self.image_display = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.scaled_image)
        self.panel.configure(image=self.image_display)
        print(self.city)
        self.display = self.image_display


def main():
    app = UserInt()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Does the program crash? Do you get an error? Does it display the wrong image? Does the image appear in the wrong place? ...

Comment: `command = self.app.update_image()` means to call `update_image()` RIGHT NOW, and save its return value (which is None) as the function to be executed when the button is clicked.  Get rid of the parentheses, so you are passing the actual function, rather than its result.

Comment: You are supposed to pass a function as `command`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is pointed out by jasonharper in the comments above.

The problem comes from this line:

```
        self.random_100_button = tk.Button(text = 'Random from top 100', width = 50, command = self.app.update_image())
```

Where you set the attribute `command` to equal `self.app.update_image()` you are executing the function and assigning the value of `None` to `command`.

Removing the parentheses `()` from the declaration ought to resolve the problem as you are assigning the function itself to the value of `command` and not the returned value of the function.